# How can I use a reserved keyword as an identifier in my JSON wrapper class

Tags: apex, json, wrapper-class

From salesforce Trying to `Create PayPal payment`, In Create Payment method request object has Items with Currency like below

```
  "name": "hat",
            "description": "Brown hat.",
            "quantity": "5",
            "price": "3",
            "tax": "0.01",
            "sku": "1",
            "currency": "USD"
```

I can't able to use as a `currency` in Apex, Identifier name is reserved: currency

```
@AuraEnabled
public string currency {get;set;}
```

**Error** `Identifier name is reserved: currency`

Comment: I disagree with this question being closed. The marked duplicate is about simple deserialization (reserved keywords aren't an issue in the duplicate), while this one is about _serializing_ data where the third party receiving the data uses a reserved keyword (for apex) in the payload.

Answer (score 3):

If you were deserializing, this is a scenario where you'd use *untyped* deserialization. Since untyped deserialization keeps all of they keys as strings, reserved keywords are not an issue.

```java
Map<String, Object> untypedResult = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(myJSON);

// handling an untyped deserialization involves a lot of casting
String myCurrency = (String)untypedResult.get('currency');
```

Since you're trying to do the opposite here, and *serialize* data with a reserved keyword, all you really need to do is the same thing, but in reverse.

That is to say, create a `Map<String, Object>`, and then serialize that map.

```java
Map<String, Object> objMap = new Map<String, Object>{
    'name' => wrapper.name,
    'description' => wrapper.description,
    ...
    // You'll need to change your wrapper class to use a valid identifier
    //   but, since you're in control of this entire process, you can easily say
    //   "oh yeah, this one particular field needs to be called something else in the
    //   JSON
    'currency' => wrapper.currencyType
};

String myJSON = JSON.serialize(objMap);
```

I imagine there are other ways to tackle this problem, but this is likely the most straightforward approach.